# How to refresh and entity object after a newly created object context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Lets say, i have an `EntityObject` called `someProduct` :

```
//Get the object
Product someProduct = someObjectContext.Product.First();

//At runtime at some point, recreate the ObjectContext
someObjectContext = new SomeObjectContext();

//Try to refresh someProduct on the new ObjectContext
someObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, someProduct);
```

When the third line executes, it throws an exception:

> The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.

Is this the correct way to refresh the `EntityObject` on a newly create `ObjectContext`?

**EDIT:**

The reason for new `ObjectContext` is to refresh all the dirty `EntityObjects`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First attach the entity to the context before refresh,

```
someObjectContext.Products.Attach(someProduct);
```

or

```
someObjectContext.Set<Product>().Attach(someProduct);
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the someProduct was retrieved using a different ObjectContext you need to use `someObjectContext.Attach(someProduct)`.

The refresh is used to refresh the cache of the ObjectContext, It needs an entity selected from the same Object Context.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the some product with object, then only you can refresh the object.

This refresh is used for refreshing the previously created cache related to object content.

I have used the following code in project. It working fine.

objectContext.attach(someProduct);